# How to update emulator in Android Studio to newest Google Play Services Version

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps-api-3

I'm using version 11.6.0 for the google play services maps, but my emulator is running an older version.I get a message saying "App Name won't run unless you update Google Play Services." How can I update the emulator to run the most current version of the google play services?

Comment: upgrade using the playstore in the emulator

Comment: I don’t see that for my emulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to update your Android version. Click Tools, Android, SDK Manager, you should see all your installed Android versions. The version you are currently using should have the status `update available`, select it and click apply.
Your version of Google Play is updated and everything should work.

Comment: I clicked the option to update, but It says the following: The following components will be deleted:
- Android SDK Platform 24, Revision: 2
- Sources for Android 24, Revision: 1
- Google APIs, Revision: 1
- Google APIs Intel x86 Atom System Image, Revision: 8

Comment: Would this harm anything?

Comment: I guess it's just that Android Studio deletes the old versions. You can try to install a different API version so your version does not get overwritten. Are you sure there's no message saying: The following components will be installed: ... When I select update on already installed versions they are not deleted. The checkbox can be empty (delete everything), filled with "-" (do nothing) or filled with a tick (update). Are you sure there is a tick in the checkbox?